# How do I change the breed of links?

Tags: netlogo

Here I want to change the breed of certain links too inactive, I am trying to use the following code which shows the below described error. Can anyone of you help me with the code please

```
directed-link-breed [active-links active-link] 

directed-link-breed [inactive-links inactive-link]

to link-network

 ask nodes
  [

   create-active-links-to other nodes
    [

      let num-links count links

      let link-freq round (num-links * link-chance / 100)

      ask n-of link-freq links
        [
          set breed inactive-links
          hide-link
        ]
    ]
  ]

 layout

end

to layout

 repeat 10 [layout-spring nodes links  0.2 5 0.1 ]

 display

end
```

> Error: There is already a INACTIVE-LINK with endpoints node 75 and
>   node 28 error while inactive-link 75 28 running SET    called by
>   procedure LINK-NETWORK
>
> called by procedure SETUP-NODES
>
> called by procedure SETUP
>
> called by Button 'setup'

Comment: Can you post the setup-nodes procedure code? That will give us a hint to find the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just ask for it, as you are doing:

```
undirected-link-breed [alinks alink]
undirected-link-breed [blinks blink]

to test
  ca
  crt 2
  ask turtle 0 [create-alink-with turtle 1]
  ask alink 0 1 [set breed blinks]
  show blink 0 1
end
```

But it is not going to work when there is already a link between the turtles that has the new breed.